# c++ how to print output of factorial program recursively

Tags: c++, output, factorial

i want to ask a very simple question.
A simple c++ code to compute factorial of any number is as following:

```
rslt=1;
for(q=fctrl;q>=1;q--)
{
 rslt=rslt*q;
}
cout<<fctrl<<"! = "<<rslt;
```

A sample run of fctrl=4,  the output is like this "4!=24"
I don't want it that way, instead i want it to print like this "4x3x2x1=24"

Can somebody help me please??

Answer (score 1):

You could just modify your loop:

```
for(int q = factrl; q >= 1; q--){
    rslt = rslt * q;
    cout << q;
    if(q != 1) cout << "x";
}
cout << "=" << rslt << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have recursive algorithm - this is iterative solution.

To achive what you want, just output the current loop variable inside it:

```
rslt=1;
for(q=fctrl;q>=1;q--)
{
   rslt=rslt*q;

   // output q
   cout << q;
   if(q != 1)
   {
       cout << "x";
   }
}
cout<<" = "<<rslt;
```

The condition `if(q != 1)` is there to prevent from writing an extra `x` at the end of the statement.

Comment: oh, so that's the story... i 've tried like this before but it keeps prompting the exrra x at the end. btw thanks a lot brother